# CASE in WHERE clause - passing multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to pass multiple cases inside where clause

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbname].[dbo].[tablename] CD, 
     [dbname].[dbo].Applications_N_Device_Master ADM
WHERE 
    CD.Product_ID = ADM.Product_ID
    AND CD.Reg_Date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
    AND CD.CompType_ID = '2' 
    AND cd.closed IN (CASE 
                         WHEN @Status = 'yes' OR 'NO' 
                            THEN @status
                            ELSE 'YES', 'NO'
                      END)
ORDER BY 
    CD.Comp_ID DESC
```

I get an error on the `else 'YES','NO'` part

Comment: The else should return just a single value; 'YES' or 'NO'.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbname].[dbo].[tablename] CD,  
     [dbname].[dbo].Applications_N_Device_Master ADM
WHERE CD.Product_ID = ADM.Product_ID 
  AND CD.Reg_Date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate 
  AND CD.CompType_ID='2' 
  AND (
        (@status IN ('yes', 'NO') AND cd.closed = @status) OR
        (@status NOT IN ('yes', 'NO') AND cd.closed IN ('YES', 'NO'))
      )
ORDER BY 
    CD.Comp_ID DESC
```

You might want to do a `ISNULL` with `@status` to handle null values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [dbname].[dbo].[tablename] CD, 
              [dbname].[dbo].Applications_N_Device_Master ADM 
WHERE CD.Product_ID = ADM.Product_ID 
  AND CD.Reg_Date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate 
  AND CD.CompType_ID='2' 
  AND cd.closed in (CASE WHEN @Status='yes'THEN 
                         WHEN @Status='no' THEN @status 
                         ELSE 'YOURELSEPART' END) 
ORDER BY CD.Comp_ID DESC
```

I think this will solve your issue

Comment: I think that you have missed something in your first CASE. `CASE WHEN @Status='yes' THEN <something_here>`